# Помогите с udp c++ winsocket2

Tags: сокет, c++

Есть задача: На с++ winsocket2 необходимо с клиента отправить широковещательную дейтаграмму и чтоб сервер клиенту отправил свой ip адрес. Я могу отправить с клиента на определенный сервер(если есть его ip адрес), но не могу отправить широковещательное сообщение.

Если кто в этом разбирается напишите пожалуйста. Все примеры, которые находил я вываливались с ошибками 10037 и еще многими разными.

Comment: В nix\* для клиентского сокета нужно вызывать (`man 2 setsockopt`)

    socklen_t n = 1;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &n, sizeof(n));


перед sendto(). 

Думаю, в винде примерно так же ([подробности здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

А серверу в `bind()` поставьте `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: Спасибо, но решение проблемы оказалось достаточно простым.

Во всех реализациях что я находил был сокет инициализирован следующим образом

my_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

И буквально пару минут назад понял в чем была ошибка.

Нужно было сокет инициализировать следующим образом
my_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);
и все сразу заработало.

Comment: @boikov, заработало без `SO_BROADCAST`?

А `IPPROTO_UDP` это, видимо, что-то виндузовое. Традиционно 0 в поле протокола для ` socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)` означает взять протокол по умолчанию для заданных типа и домена.